# htaccess A quick move, from pagefor.local/USERNAME to pagefor/USERNAME.local

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mamp

Morning all,

I have spent Sunday attempting to rewrite a domain to no avail. I'm using MAMP and have changed my Hosts folder and MAMP httpd.conf with the following :

Addition to hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   apagefor.local
```

Addition to httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName pagefor.local
    DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pagefor
</VirtualHost>
```

This allowed me get rid of the pesky localhost:8888/pagefor/ to just using a nice local url of `pagefor.local` this all works perfectly. But now im trying to attempt to do a htaccess rewrite if a username is placed directly after the domain. Allowing me to do the following:

Change this:

```
pagefor.local/LEE
```

to this:

```
pagefor/LEE.local
```

So what have I tired? Well I thought I could do something like the following (within .htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^`pagefor.local` [NC]
RewriteRule ^pagefor.local/([A-Za-z0-9-.]+)  `http://pagefor/$1.local`
```

Im still trying to workout how to do this, if anyone can tell me where im going... And if im on even on the right path (pun intended :) ) Thank you.

**Update**

I have managed to get the url to change from `http://pagefor.local/lee` to `http://pagefor/lee.local` Thanks to anubhava. The only contention I have is I originally have everything go to my index.php file which controls the entire application... So would it be possible to do the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}              ^pagefor\.local$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-.]+)$   http://pagefor/$1.local [NC,L]
```

Then Have the following line to get $1 into my index.php:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-.]+).local$    index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

Therefore when the Url is pagefor/lee.local its on the following index.php?url=lee. I tired the above but it did not succeed. I hope im on the right track to solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pagefor\.local$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-.]+)$ http://pagefor/$1.local [L,R]
```

Comment: this did redirect the url... But for some reason the browser will state it cannot fin the server pagefor? Any ideas? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: No where in your hosts file you have an entry for the host `pagefor` hence you're getting this error. Remember you made an entry for `pagefor.local` only.

Comment: How would i go about making an entry for pagefor/$variable.local ?

Comment: I think you need to understand these things a bit. In the hosts file you can have hosts aliases, so adding a line like `127.0.0.1 pagefor` will work for you.

Comment: I added that line to my hosts file... And it seems to be working, thankyou. Just one last question this should still work live if the url is pagefor.co.uk or pagefor.com... As long as i make the stated changed above from .local to .com ?

Comment: Yes that is correct, just replace `pagefor` to `pagefor.co.uk` when you want enw redirection.

Comment: Also can you mark this answer as accepted if you think it has helped you solving your problem.

Comment: Thank you @anubhava you have greatly helped me in understanding htaccess, I will mark your answer as correct. Thanks again.

Comment: Yea it worked, I tried the following to get everything to go through my index.php (So the app works off the main controller) Could i get the redirect to go to index.php?url=$1 ? 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^apagefor\.local$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-.]+)$   http://pagefor/$1.local [L,R] 

Could I just place this under the above rule?
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9-.]+).local$    index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
Could this work? I think i might be going about it a little wrong?

Comment: Pls provide this .htaccess code in your question otherwise it is difficult to understand.

Comment: I improved the question :)

Comment: You have extra `home/` in your RewriteRule and that is causing problem. Remove that and it will work.